# Advanced Custom Fields & Nested Flexible content

Tags: wordpress

I have a slightly complicated setup which works as follows:

-- Repeater Field (Page Section)

---- Choose BG Color

---- Choose BG Image

------ Flexible Content Field (Page Section Row)

--------Layouts (Rows: Full page width, 50/50 page width etc)

I am storing the background image into a variable like so:

```
 <?php if(get_sub_field('section_background_image')) { 
   $bgImg = get_sub_field('section_background_image'); 
}; ?>
```

Then calling it like so:

```
<?php if( isset($bgImg) ) { ?>
   <img class="section-bg-img" src="<?php echo $bgImg ?>" />                                
<?php } ?>
```

But the image does not display. If I place the code before the flexible content row loop, it appears, but not within.

I hope that makes sense! I can provide full code if necessary via email or similar service.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide full code. We've done one similar to this on a recent job. It's very picky. Are your images set in ACF as an array or URL?

Comment: Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/imx3DMdX I'm currently using images via URL

Comment: Please ignore lines 24/26; they are now removed.